# To Get List of all the Hyperparameters using python for a Machine Learning Algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I wanted to get the list of all the **Hyperparameters** for the Machine Learning Algorithm. I wanted to give it as an input for the Grid Search. I am currently using Jupyter Notebook. Is there any command to get this list of all the hyperparameters ?

Comment: If you are using Jupyter, then you can press Shift + Tab on Windows to view all possible hyperparameters when you are instantiating the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The first option is using `Shift + Tab`.

Moreover using `Shift + Tab  + Tab` makes it much more user friendly.

Sometimes the signature/documentation of function with `Shift+Tab` may not work. then you can also use `<function>?` and execute the cell.

This also will lead you to documentation, here you can see all the Hyperplanes.